# Lighting your sons menorah(chanukiya) by mistake

Tags: menora-chanukia

What should one do in a case where one sets his menorah up with oil and his son's menorah with candles, but after he said the brachos he lit his son's menorah? Should he light his menorah and extinguish his son's menorah, or should he leave it and let his son light his menorah?

Two factors that I thought of to be considered:

1) hidur mitzvah of using oil, so maybe he should light his and extinguish his son's, or maybe not since some poskim hold candles are lchatchilah.

2) bizyon to the mitzvah. If one would light their menorah and extinguish their son's menorah it may be a bizyon.

What would be the best way to act in such a scenario?

Comment: If Hadlaka Oseh Mitzva, then he's just done and nothing he can do now changes anything. As Kohelet said https://www.sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.1.15 מְעֻוָּ֖ת לֹא־יוּכַ֣ל לִתְקֹ֑ן וְחֶסְר֖וֹן לֹא־יוּכַ֥ל לְהִמָּנֽוֹת

Comment: Did he light his son's menorah semi-on purpose?  Or did he just accidentally hit it with the fire while he was moving the ligher or shamas or whatever to his own menorah?  If it's the second maybe he wasn't yotzei at all.

Comment: He lit it thinking its his menorah